# "Statement expected" error after inserting JSLR <c:out> tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

"Statement expected" error after inserting JSLR `<c:out>` tag

```
    <c:forEach var="dslr" items="${dslrs}">
            <tr>
                <td><a 
href="javascript:get_dslr( <c:out value="${dslr.dslrId}"/> )" target="_self">description</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

The end of `<c:out` at right after `>` is highlighted as error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your href as

```
    href="javascript:get_dslr('<c:out value="${dslr.dslrId}"/>')"
```